# Styling tomahawk upload file component

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf-2

I am trying to style the `t:inputFileUpload` element, I tried this solution [styling an input type=file](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), which is putting another input element and an image to occupy the same place the `t:inputFileUpload` takes.That is my code

```
<div id="file-div">
    <h:inputText styleClass="replace-upload" id="fake-input" />
        <div class="browse-img">
            <span class="browse-button">#{msgs.select}</span>
        </div>
    <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{createListBean.uploadedFile}"
        size="22" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.csv" type="file" style="z-index :2;opacity:0;position:relative;"
        onchange="changeFakeFile()" styleClass="file-real" />
</div>
```

And my styling

```
.replace-upload {
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE !important;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 #CCCCCC inset !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 5px !important;
    width: 157px !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.browse-img {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 76px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 171px;
    top:-2px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
}

.browse-button {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now when user clicks on the fake input element he would be actually clicking over the tomahawk element , the main problem is the path he selected doesn't show over the fake input, that is why I added some javascript to it function

```
changeFakeFile(){
    var x = $('.file-real').val();
    $('.replace-upload').text(x);}
```

The problem is the fake input value is changed but the value doesn't show to the user,how to make it appear?

Comment: $('.replace-upload').val($('.file-real')[0].files[0].name); or maybe just val() is the only change you need...

Comment: what files[0] refers to?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `$('.replace-upload').text(x);` with `$('.replace-upload').val(x);` and it worked.